# Proving the Riemann integral exists

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, riemann-integration

Given that $f(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$  and $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$, prove that

$$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{n^2 -k^2} = \int_{0}^{1} f.$$

I am not exactly sure where to begin with this problem nor do I really understand what my plan of solving it should be. I appreciate your help and nudges in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

The left side can be converted into a Riemann sum:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{n^2 - k^2} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{1 - (k/n)^2}
$$
Since $f(x)$ is integrable, the limit exists and equals to
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{1 - (k/n)^2} = \int_0^1 dx\,\sqrt{1-x^2} = \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx
$$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $\sqrt{n^2-k^2} = n\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2}$